# Is it possible to change External Git link in Deployment centre in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

`Azure OpenAI` has automatically deployed an app for me. It seems that the src is repository whose location is mentioned in the `deployment centre`. I have forked the repo, made a change in an html file (all done online in `git`, I didn't download the src and used an IDE. I don't want to do it either). Is it possible to point the `App` to new repo ? How do I do it? How do I make the `app service` start the app using the new repo with my change?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There suppose to be option, setup new source in deployment center but first current need to be removed. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github) how to set up this for app service

Comment: Thanks. I got stuck at a new point. Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789704/not-able-to-deploy-a-modified-version-of-git-repo-in-azure-app-service