# Not able to deploy a modified version of git repo in Azure App Service

Tags: github-actions, cicd, azure-appservice

I created an `azure open ai` application and deployed it using the `playground`. This automatically created a `web app` and an `app service`. I found that the code of the application is at https://github.com/microsoft/sample-app-aoai-chatGPT

I want to make a change in the repo and deploy application from the modified repo. So I forked the repo and made change to file `frontend-src-pages-layout-layout.tsx`. I changed the text “Azure AI” to “Azure AI by me”. Then I disconnected the old repo and created a new connection (with option to use the existing workflow file)

[image]

I saw this message

[image]

Then I restarted the app. However, I don't see the change. The page still looks like original. I expected the `Azure AI` text on top left to be `Azure AI by me`.

[image]

What am I missing

update
I went to `actions` in `github` and saw the message

[image]

I enabled workflow.

I didn't see any workflow getting executed

[image]

Then I made another change in `layout.tsx` and directly committed it to `main` branch. I am making changes directly in `github` using the `edit` button for the file.

I see that a workflow execution was attempted but failed.

[image]

[image]

It is asking for username. I don't know why though.  I haven't set up `ACR_USERNAME` as I thought that because I am changing an existing app service code, i don't need to. Do I and how?

[image]

After fixing the `ACR issue` (thanks to [Github workflow failing with error - Error: Error: Input required and not supplied: username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791212/github-workflow-failing-with-error-error-error-input-required-and-not-suppli) and [Azure Container Registry and Github actions - denied: requested access to the resource is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791909/azure-container-registry-and-github-actions-denied-requested-access-to-the-re))  I was able to execute the workflow. I see  that the change to pushed. However, I don't see the change in my app.

[image]

Not sure if it is relevant but in the `web app` deployment, I don't see any logs from the time the workflow was executed.

[image]

I thought maybe I need to redeploy but that is failing.

[image]

My `.github/workflow` file is `.github/workflows/docker-image.yml`.

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Azure Container Registry Login
      uses: Azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        # Container registry username
        username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
        # Container registry password
        password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}
        # Container registry server url
        login-server: ${{ secrets.ACR_LOGIN_SERVER }}
        
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run:         
        docker build . --file WebApp.Dockerfile --tag craistudiodemoresouce383718707273.azurecr.io/sample-app-aoai-chatgpt:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')_$GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER;
        docker tag craistudiodemoresouce383718707273.azurecr.io/sample-app-aoai-chatgpt:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')_$GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER craistudiodemoresouce383718707273.azurecr.io/sample-app-aoai-chatgpt:latest;
        docker push craistudiodemoresouce383718707273.azurecr.io/sample-app-aoai-chatgpt:$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')_$GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER;
        docker push craistudiodemoresouce383718707273.azurecr.io/sample-app-aoai-chatgpt:latest;
```

I have added the following section in the end

```
- name: Build and deploy Container App
      uses: azure/container-apps-deploy-action@v1
      with:
        appSourcePath: ${{ github.workspace }}/src
        acrName: craistudiodemoresouce383718707273
        containerAppName: careeradvisorbot
        resourceGroup: rg-aistudiodemoresouce
```

but I am now getting error

```
Run azure/container-apps-deploy-action@v1
Run CA_GH_ACTION_START_MILLISECONDS=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
Run az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
WARNING: Command group 'config' is experimental and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
Run CA_GH_ACTION_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name *** --output json --expose-token | jq -r '.accessToken')
WARNING: Unable to get AAD authorization tokens with message: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
WARNING: Unable to get admin user credentials with message: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
ERROR: Unable to authenticate using AAD or admin login credentials. Please specify both username and password in non-interactive mode.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I later changed `workflow.yml` to

```
- uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

I saw that the workflow completed successfully

[image]

I see the following message in deployment centre

[image]

but when I restarted the app, I got error

[image]

I guess this is where I need `service principal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you haven't actually executed the workflow. That is, you updated the `build and deployment workflow` by referencing your forked repo, but you haven't actually executed it.

From your question I understand that you first made the changes in the forked repo, and then changed app service to point to the new repo. This wouldn't trigger the workflow.

Because your workflow has a trigger when you `push` to `main` branch, you're going to need to make a change, commit it, and then push it to `main`.

This should trigger the workflow and update your app.

EDIT: Once you've correctly executed the basic workflow that builds your new updated docker container and stores it in your registry, you're going to need to actually deploy that to your `WebApp`.
For this, I personally prefer to have a separate `CD` workflow, but for now, you can easily integrate this into your current workflow and work from there.

You're going to want to head to the Azure Portal and then download your `Publish Profile`. This will provide you with a file; the contents of which you're going to want to copy.

Then, you'll need to head to your repository in GitHub, click on `Settings` and then `Secrets and variables` --> `Actions`.
Here, you'll create a `New Repository Secret` that you can name `AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE`, and where you'll paste the full contents of your `Publish Profile` from before.

You are also going to need to follow the same steps as above to store your `Azure Credentials` as a variable named `AZURE_CREDENTIALS`. You can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/Azure/login?tab=readme-ov-file#login-with-a-service-principal-secret) to do this.

Now, you need to open up `.github/workflows/{yourworkflow}` in a code editor, and add the following:

```
deployjob:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:

    - name: Log in to Azure
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Build and deploy Container App
      uses: azure/container-apps-deploy-action@v1
      with:
        appSourcePath: ${{ github.workspace }}/src
        acrName: myregistry
        containerAppName: my-container-app
        resourceGroup: my-rg
```

Make sure you replace `acrName`, `containerAppName` and `resourceGroup` values to match yours.

Comment: thanks. You helped me look in right direction. I am still facing issues with running workflow. I have updated the question. Could you take a look please. I am new to this so not really sure what is going on at times

Comment: Was finally able to run the `workflow`. When I commited a change, a workflow ran. However, I still don't see my change. I see that the changes were `pushed` to main? I also restarted the app. What I might be missing?

Comment: I just edited my response with more instructions to allow you to actually deploy the modified version of the app to Azure.

Comment: Firstly, thanks. I wouldn't have been able to make progress without your help. I'll try the steps. I have updated the question to add information about the deployment file which was already existing in the repo. Curious, how come the deployment section isn't there already? How did the deployment happened the first time without it ?

Comment: If I need to do it just once, because I only want to see how it works, can I do it without setting up service principal and just copy/paste credentials in the workflow file?

Comment: I tried a different approach but still not luck - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77812537/app-service-not-picking-code-from-new-forked-git-repository